# Using 'require' with esm - ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, es6-modules

I have been updating my codebase to replace instances of 'require' with import syntax as per esm guidelines, but have hit a snag with a few examples where I'm not sure what the correct syntax is:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
require('dotenv').config();
```

What is the correct way to convert these to import syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a reference to express router by first importing the `express` package

```
import express from "express";
```

and then accessing the `Router` property on it

```
const router = express.Router();
```

You can do the similar thing for `dotenv` package.

```
// import the "dotenv" package
import dotenv from "dotenv";

// call the config function
dotenv.config();
```